# Необходимо уменьшить php код

Tags: php

Это исполняемый скрипт для масштабирования изображения, но он очень большой, поэтом вот ссылка.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Масштабирование изображений

> Итак, пусть у нас есть файл в любом
> поддерживаемом GD формате, и мы хотим
> создать “превьюшку” заданного размера
> в формате JPEG. Разработаем для этой
> цели функцию img_resize(). Код функции
> содержит подробные комментарии - так
> что чтение не должно вызвать
> затруднений.

```
<?php
/*
Функция img_resize(): генерация thumbnails
Параметры:
$src - имя исходного файла
$dest - имя генерируемого файла
$width, $height - ширина и высота генерируемого изображения, в пикселях
Необязательные параметры:
$rgb - цвет фона, по умолчанию - белый
$quality - качество генерируемого JPEG, по умолчанию - максимальное (100)
*/
function img_resize($src, $dest, $width, $height, $rgb=0xFFFFFF, $quality=100)
{
  if (!file_exists($src)) return false;

  $size = getimagesize($src);

  if ($size === false) return false;

  // Определяем исходный формат по MIME-информации, предоставленной
  // функцией getimagesize, и выбираем соответствующую формату
  // imagecreatefrom-функцию.
  $format = strtolower(substr($size['mime'], strpos($size['mime'], '/')+1));
  $icfunc = "imagecreatefrom" . $format;
  if (!function_exists($icfunc)) return false;

  $x_ratio = $width / $size[0];
  $y_ratio = $height / $size[1];

  $ratio = min($x_ratio, $y_ratio);
  $use_x_ratio = ($x_ratio == $ratio);

  $new_width = $use_x_ratio ? $width : floor($size[0] * $ratio);
  $new_height = !$use_x_ratio ? $height : floor($size[1] * $ratio);
  $new_left = $use_x_ratio ? 0 : floor(($width - $new_width) / 2);
  $new_top = !$use_x_ratio ? 0 : floor(($height - $new_height) / 2);

  // Читаем в память файл изображения с помощью функции imagecreatefrom...
  $isrc = $icfunc($src);
  // Создаем новое изображение
  $idest = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);

  // Заливка цветом фона
  imagefill($idest, 0, 0, $rgb);
  // Копируем существующее изображение в новое с изменением размера:
  imagecopyresampled(
    $idest, // Идентификатор нового изображения
    $isrc, // Идентификатор исходного изображения
     $new_left, $new_top, // Координаты (x,y) верхнего левого угла в новом изображении
    0, 0, // Координаты (x,y) верхнего левого угла копируемого блока
           // существующего изображения
    $new_width, // Новая ширина копируемого блока
    $new_height, // Новая высота копируемого блока
    $size[0], // Ширина исходного копируемого блока
    $size[1] // Высота исходного копируемого блока
  );
  // Сохраняем результат в JPEG-файле: функция imagejpeg, может выводить
  // результат своей работы не только в броузер, но и в файл. Для этого
  // следует указать имя файла в необязательном втором параметре.
  // Функция imagejpeg имеет и третий необязательный параметр - качество
  // изображения.
  imagejpeg($idest, $dest, $quality);

  imagedestroy($isrc);
  imagedestroy($idest);

  return true;
}
?>
```

Пример использования:

```
<?php
if (img_resize('original.jpg', 'small.jpg', 100, 100))
  echo 'Image resized OK';
else
  echo 'Resize failed!';
?>
```

Comment: Можно сделать чуть по-проще, воспользовавшись функцией [`imagecreatefromstring`][1], тогда код создания исходного изображения будет:

    $isrc = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($src));
    if ($isrc === FALSE) {
        die ("Invalid image format");
    }
    $src_width = imagesx($isrc);
    $src_height = imagesy($isrc);
    // ну и так далее

  [1]:http://ru.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromstring.php

Comment: .

    $image = new Imagick('image.jpg');
    $image->cropThumbnailImage(100, 100); // или $image->thumbnailImage(100, 100);
    $image->writeImage('image_thumb.jpg');
    $image->destroy();

Comment: Может я не понимаю чего то, но все же скажу. Тут почти все так как мне не надо. Здесь скрипт не определяет каким изображение было изначально, горизонтальным или вертикальным, из за этого масштабирование будет не корректным. Также нет решения для создания корректного имени файла. Может получится так что 2 файла будут с одинаковыми именами.....